# Loop through imagedata in a HTM5 canvas vertically

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to **loop into a canvas vertically**. I mean, Looping through the first column, the the 2nd, etc.

My first goal is to **colorize the first half of the width**. My code is acting weird and the problem is... I do not know why!

```
loopVertical = function (data, canvas){
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width*2; x+=4) {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
            data[x+y*canvas.width*4] = 255;         
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

**The result: red stripes on my image.** And that's not what I want.

*After I will need to divide the image in smaller images if I have a vertical line of transparent pixels, but this is not the topic of the question :)*

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know about html5 canvas and the image data, but according to [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/), my guess is that your outer loop is wrong. Apparently, you also need to take care of operator precedence when calculating the index of your data. Maybe something like :

```
loopVertical = function (data, canvas){
    // first half of the width
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width / 2; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
            data[(x+y*canvas.width)*4] = 255;      
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```